# How do I know which color is applied to which component in ColorScheme flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, themes, material3

The description says like below and its not ENOUGH!!!! and I am tired!!

```
ColorScheme is a set of 25 colors based on the Material spec that can be used to configure the color properties of most components.

The main accent color groups in the scheme are primary, secondary, and tertiary.
```

I'd like to know which color applied to which component in flutter

For example,

The `primary` color is applied to `FloatingActionButton` like that!

Comment: I'm afraid this is nowhere well documented. The only option often is too dig deeply into the code of the widgets to see where they take their color from. I also find it frustrating sometimes

Comment: In this link, https://m3.material.io/components. @Ivo
 I found that in every component there is a `Specs` tab, and I can see the color is given but not sure

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it says, Flutter follows the Material design system and color scheme, so you can know what widgets and elements those colors are used from the official Material design website, check it:

https://m2.material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html